# Getting a sense of $f(x) = x (\log x)^6$

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

The nature of the curve $f(x) = x (\log_{2} x)^6$ is baffling me. I expect the curve looks rather like plot of $f(x) = x\log_{2} x$; however probing on Wolfram Alpha says it does not. The shape of the graph looks more like a squashed $f(x) = x^2$ which is not all that surprising but just doesn't seem right.

$x (\log_{2} x)^6$:

[image: x (x\log_{2} x)^6]

$x log_{2} x$:

[image: x\log_{2} x$]

To find out what the growth curve is really like I put in $f(x) = x^2 / x (\log_{2} x)^6$ and for comparison $f(x) = x^2 / x (\log_{2} x)$. These curves look very different from either interpretation.

$x^2 / (x\log_{2} x)^6$:

[image: $x^2 / (x\log_{2} x)^6$]

$x^2 / (x\log_{2} x)$:

[image: $x^2 / (x\log_{2} x)$]

My best guess is I can't get answers I understand because the range where this takes on its typical shape is much larger than $10000$. I don't care about when x is really small. $x$ is domain-restricted to be $> 1$

Incidentally this is a real function that came up at my work some time ago, and it's been on my mind on and off ever since. The original form was $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n tx \prod_{j=1}^i k_{j}\log_{2} x$ where $t$ is effectively constant and $k_{n}$ was a statistics table with each term being between $1$ and $0$ and $k_{7}$ turned out to be exactly $0$ so the equation terminated with $6$ dominating.

[What's the tag for interesting range of a function?]

Comment: I don't see why graphing those other two functions is supposed to help.  Why not graph (include a graph of) the function you ask about in the title and first line of the body of your Question?

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \log x gives $\log x$ instead of log x which gives $log x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key fact are that

$$(\log_2x)^6\ge0$$

$$(\log_21)^6 = 0$$

$$x\to 0^+ \implies  x(\log_2 x)^6\to0$$

thus there exist a maximum for $x\in(0,1)$.

The difference for $x>1$ with $x\log_2x$ can be understood taking a look at the second derivatives of the functions

[second derivative $x(\log_2 x)^6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second%20derivative%20x*log_2%20x%5E6,%20x%3D0..100)

[second derivative $x\log_2x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second%20derivative%20x*log_2%20x,%20x%3D0..100)

Comment: It took me awhile to figure out the first graph needs its range changed so it looks like what you said it looks like. I ended up using 0..10000

Answer (score 1):

The vertical asymptote in your first graph comes because you have $x^6$ in the denominator, so overall you have $x^{-4},$ which goes to $+\infty$ as $ \to 0$.  As $x$ increases $x \log^6 x$ will increase faster than $x$, but eventually slower than any $x^{1+\epsilon}$